# Basic MVC construction, ActionListner doesnt work

Tags: java, swing, model-view-controller

I wanted to do really simple MVC project, when i click on the button, I'd like to see "napis" on my console, but the ActionListener doesn't work properly. Any thoughts ? (If i've done something wrong with post please be understanding its my first post here :))

```
public class Model {

public String napis (){
    return "napis";
}
```

}

```
public class View {
private JFrame frame;
private JLabel label;
private JButton button;

public View (){
    frame = new JFrame();
    label = new JLabel("Napis");
    button = new JButton("click");

    frame.add(label);
    frame.add(button);
    frame.setSize(500,500);
    button.setSize(30,30);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}

public void addActionListener(ActionListener click){
    button.addActionListener(click);
}
```

}

```
public class Controller {
    private Model model;
    private View view = new View();

    public Controller (final Model model, View view) {
    view.addActionListener(
      new ActionListener(){


        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            model.napis();
        }
      }      
    );{

    }

    }
}
```

ofc all imports are fixed.

Comment: So, I'm looking through you're code and I'm confused. You never seem to construct a `Controller`, but also, in your `Controller`, you create a new instance of `View`, but also pass it an instance of `View` ... so which is which?

Answer (score 1):

`model.napis();` doesn't write anything in the console :

```
public String napis (){
    return "napis";
}
```

It returns simply a `String`.

This should do it :

```
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    System.out.println(model.napis());
}
```

Comment: Yup, just tried it, and still no results, it was a simple example, but also yesterday i couldn't access another window by public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){}

Comment: " it was a simple example". With the actual code I don't see any problem. Add a main(String[] args) method and it should work. For example :  `public static void main(String[] args) {
  View view = new View();
  new Controller(new Model(), view);
 }` With another code I cannot guess where the problem is  if it is not specified in the question.

Answer (score 0):

In your controller class, change

```
model.napis();
```

to

```
System.out.println(model.napis());
```

What your problem is that the action listener takes the String but does nothing with it. What you have to do is to print the returned String.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so your code is a little confusing.  Your `Controller` is creating an instance of `View`, but it's also been passed an instance of `View`.

The instance it create's does not have the `ActionListener` attached to it, but the one you pass in does.

Both `View`s are create and showing a `JFrame`

[image: Due frames]

Because the instance of `View` you're passing gets created first, it appears first, but the instance of `View` which your `Controller` creates gets created second, it appears over the top - but it does not have an `ActionListener` attached to it...

So, the first thing you should do, is get rid of the instance of the `View` that the `Controller` is creating

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        Controller controller = new Controller(new Model(), new View());
    }

    public class Model {

        public String napis() {
            return "napis";
        }
    }

    public class View {

        private JFrame frame;
        private JLabel label;
        private JButton button;

        public View() {
            frame = new JFrame();
            label = new JLabel("Napis");
            button = new JButton("click");

            frame.add(label);
            frame.add(button);
            frame.setSize(500, 500);
            button.setSize(30, 30);
            frame.setVisible(true);
        }

        public void addActionListener(ActionListener click) {
            button.addActionListener(click);
        }
    }

    public class Controller {

        private Model model;
        private View view;

        public Controller(final Model model, View view) {
            this.view = view;
            this.model = model;
            view.addActionListener(
                new ActionListener() {

                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    System.out.println("Clicked");
                    this.model.napis();
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

You should also be focused on the side effect that your `View`'s constructor is creating, creating and showing the frame probably isn't the right choice here

I would also encourage you to do some research into the concept of "code to interface not implementation" as it's one of the key aspects of MVC